# Select dates which difference will be major or equal to 1

Tags: excel, vba, date-range

Hello everyone i have the next data in a sheet of excel

[image: datasheet]

my question is how can i filter this information only taking the dates which difference is major or equal to 1, in summary i would like from visual basic classify the last table in something like this:
[image]

i really appreciate your help if someone could help me to have a code that resolve this trouble.

Comment: Will adding an extra column with `HOUR(Fecha)` do? You can filter this column on `12`. This will only be correct for this example, so if this is not what you are looking for, please add info to the question.

Comment: i solved, my solution for it (i will share soon) is take the common dates and save in differents arrays then, select for the first date the minimum value, and then save it in other array and then compare with difference what is bigger than one, and on and on, finally i have an array with values which differences is bigger than one, thank you for your opinion

Comment: "compare with difference" is not possible. When comparing stuff you will get a difference as result. For Example comparing `1` and `3`, will result in the difference `2`.  It is just a language problem, i know, but...... 

Comment: hahahah thank you, and of course i will consider it. thank u again.

Answer (score 0):

Well i will share my solution to this trouble in vba using next:

```
''dimension of variables
dim ws as worksheet

set ws=thisworkbook.worksheets(sheet1)

now i got my matrix
set arrdata = ws.range("A1").CurrentRegion

fechainicio = CDate(Format(arrdata(1)(0), "dd/mm/yy")): numfechas = UBound(arrdata, 1)
fechafin = CDate(Format(arrdata(numfechas)(0), "dd/mm/yy"))

Dim datofecharr() As Variant
m = 1
For i = fechainicio To fechafin
    k = 1
    Dim datofecha() As Variant
    For j = 1 To numfechas
    If CDate(Format(arrdata(j)(0), "dd/mm/yy")) = i Then
     ReDim Preserve datofecha(1 To k)
     datofecha(k) = arrdata(j)(0)
     k = k + 1
    End If
    Next j
ReDim Preserve datofecharr(1 To m)
    datofecharr(m) = datofecha
    m = m + 1
Next i

lendatofecharr = UBound(datofecharr, 1)
Dim fechadiariarr() As Variant

ReDim Preserve fechadiariarr(1 To 1)
''seleccionamos la fecha minima de registro
fechadiariarr(1) = WorksheetFunction.min(datofecharr(1))
m = 2
''solo tomando los datos cuya diferencia horaria sea mayor o igual a 1 día
For i = 2 To lendatofecharr
    For k = 1 To UBound(datofecharr(i))
        If datofecharr(i)(k) - fechadiariarr(m - 1) >= 1 Then
         ReDim Preserve fechadiariarr(1 To m)
         fechadiariarr(m) = datofecharr(i)(k)
         m = m + 1
        Exit For
        
     End If
    Next k
 
Next i

Dim datosdiariosarr() As Variant
For i = 1 To UBound(fechadiariarr, 1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(arrdata, 1)
    If fechadiariarr(i) = arrdata(j)(0) Then
    ReDim Preserve datosdiariosarr(1 To i)
    datosdiariosarr(i) = arrdata(j)
    Exit For
    
    End If
    
    Next j
Next i
```